# Map and Reduce class Attributes in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, parallel-processing

So, I am new at Hadoop and I have a question with respect to how hadoop handle the attributes of the implementation of the class Reducer or Mapper.

From what I understand, each of the instances of the reducer will be executed in a different JVM, then, there is no shared memory in between them. The question is, how Hadoop handle the concurrent access to an attribute defined outside the reducer function, if all the reducers are trying to access it. Even more, what happen if I try to instantiate a variable within the reducer. From my understanding of parallel programming, if this kind of operations are not made on a critical region or over an atomic variable, there will be a race condition.

A short example:

```
public class SequenceBuilderRed extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    private HashMap<String,myClass> myHashMap;
    protected void setup(Reducer<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, Interrupted Exception
    {
         myHashMap=new HashMap<String,myClass>();
    }

    protected void reduce(Text key Iterable<Text> values, Reducer <Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
       for(Text value:values)
       {
          if(!myHashMap.containsKey(value.toString())
          {
              myClass newObject = new myClass();
              myHashMap.put(value.toString(),newObject);
          }
       }
     }
}
```

What would happen in this case if there are different reducers with the same Text as value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, each of the instances of the reducer will be executed in a different JVM, then, there is no shared memory in between them.

Yes, each of the instances of Mapper and Reducer's will be executed in different JVM's often on different machines based on data locality. Hence, they are based on shared-nothing architecture.

> The question is, how Hadoop handle the concurrent access to an attribute defined outside the reducer function, if all the reducers are trying to access it.

Hadoop does not allow attributes defined in one Mapper/Reducer class to be shared between multiple Mapper/Reducer JVM instances. Which means that if you have specified a variable inside of your Mapper/Reducer class, like from your example `myHashMap` will be accessible from with in it's own JVM i.e. for example if your job requires 10 Reducers then each Reducer instance will create it's own `HashMap`.

To further clarify, `reduce()` method is not a concurrent method but rather will be executed sequentially in a single Reducer JVM instance so your `HashMap` will not be accessed concurrently.

So, to put it together if your job requires 10 Reducer instances, then 10 of those Reducers could run all the same time based on your cluster capacity with each of the Reducer instance having access to its own variables, and each Reducer instance will iterate over its range of keys to process and then invokes `reduce()` method for each key and values list sequentially.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: So, what would happen if I  try to acces the attributes from the clean up and set up phases? Aren't those phases unique for the whole map or reduce ?

Comment: `setup()` and `cleanup()` methods are invoked once per Mapper/Reducer JVM invocation. MapReduce framework guarantees it calls `setup()` method before initializing the `map()`/`reduce()` method calls useful for opening db connections, building collections, opening files; similarly `cleanup()` is guaranteed to be called after all the key, values are processed by Mapper/Reducer useful for closing connections.

Comment: So what would happen to an attribute modified during the reducer if I try to print it in the cleanup?

Comment: Yes, you can do that; you can print a variable being modified in the `reduce()` method in the `cleanup()` if that's what you are asking. But keep in mind that `cleanup()` method is called only after Reducer finished processing all key, value pairs.

Comment: My problem is. If each reducer will have its own attribute value, what is the value that is going to be printed in the cleanup () after

Comment: Each `cleanup()` will print attribute that is in the scope of its own JVM. So, if you assume you would want to count the number of malformed records and you are keeping track of this count and incrementing it in the `reduce()` and finally printing it out in `cleanup()` this will print count respective to that Reducer, similarly this happens on all the Reducer instances; so, if you have about 10 reducers you will see 10 print statements with count respective to each of its own Reducer. But if you want aggregated count from all Reducer instances you will have to use MapReduce Counters.

Comment: Wow, that sounds really complex, I will have to take a look at my basics again since I though there was only one cleanup for all the reducers. (and only one setup as well). Thanks anyway! this will be a long learning process.